# Add multiple CardView dynamically to Fragment xml

Tags: java, android, xml, cardview

My Android (Java) App uses Fragments to display products in a GridLayout.
Each product is a cardview with two TextViews as well as an ImageView.

I have all my products stored on a webserver in mariaDB. Fragment's OnCreate method gets my productList from server.
Now I want to dynamically create CardViews for all products returned from the server. For now, I have hardcoded the layout, but as the number of products can change, it's neccesary to create CardViews for the products dynamically.

How can I achieve this in Java?

This is how the Fragment looks:

[image: fragment_dtinks.xml]

Here's how I implemented the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.DrinksFragment">

<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="14dp"
    app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cV_water"
        style="@style/ProductCardStyle">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iV_water"
                style="@style/ImageStyle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ic_water"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tV_counterWater"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV_descWater"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_water_bottle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_descWater"
                style="@style/TextStyle"
                android:text="@string/product_water"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_counterWater"
                style="@style/TextStyle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also, here's the ProductCardStyle:

```
<style name = "ProductCardStyle">
    <item name = "cardBackgroundColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name = "android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name = "android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name = "android:layout_marginLeft">2dp</item>
    <item name = "android:layout_marginRight">2dp</item>
    <item name = "android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name = "android:layout_marginTop">2dp</item>
    <item name = "cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
    <item name = "cardElevation">8dp</item>
    <item name = "layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name = "layout_rowWeight">1</item>
</style>
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager.
You can begin with simple RecyclerView like in this article

> https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-recyclerview-33fd4ff9988e

And apply GridLayoutManager after RecyclerView implemented.

For more info:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: @Gordon.f were you able to get this working with this answer? If so, please remember to accept it. This shows other users that you've found a solution.